# How to calculate a total for a given condition on each row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have dollar and euro currencies.

I want to calculate in the last column only euro prices.

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER, 
PRODUCT, 
PRICE, 
CURRENCY, 
FROM MORE.PRODUCTS 
WHERE CUSTOMER = '1000' 

CUSTOMER    PRODUCT     PRICE   CURRENCY 
1000        BIKE        100         € 
1000        CAR         200         € 
1000        BIKE        50          $ 
1000        CANON       120         € 
1000        TRAIN       300         $
```

Example, I want `SUM` of € values only:

```
CUSTOMER    PRODUCT     PRICE   CURRENCY    TOTAL PRICE 
1000        BIKE        100         €           420 
1000        CAR         200         €           420 
1000        BIKE        50          $           420 
1000        CANON       120         €           420 
1000        TRAIN       300         $           420
```

What is best way to do this?

I tried to use a subquery in the `SELECT` clause, but I was not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to calculate the total:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, 
       PRODUCT, 
       PRICE, 
       CURRENCY, 
       SUM( CASE CURRENCY WHEN '€' THEN PRICE END ) OVER () AS TOTAL_PRICE
FROM   MORE.PRODUCTS 
WHERE  CUSTOMER = '1000'
```

**Output**:

```
CUSTOMER PRODUCT PRICE CURRENCY TOTAL_PRICE
-------- ------- ----- -------- -----------
    1000 BIKE      100 €                420
    1000 CAR       200 €                420
    1000 BIKE       50 $                420
    1000 CANON     120 €                420
    1000 TRAIN     300 $                420
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, SUM(TOTAL_PRICE)  
FROM MORE.PRODUCTS 
WHERE CUSTOMER = '1000' and CURRENCY = '€'
```

You have to filter for euro prices.

Comment: This only gets a single row with 2 columns - the sample output has not aggregated the data except in that one column.

Comment: M4tt is looking for a SUM of the euro prices.  That isn't a sample output; it includes USD.

Comment: @MT0 Is correct, you are not providing the expected output.

Comment: @Brandon The total price in the example `420 = 100 + 200 + 120` which is just the prices with the Euro currency (the `300` and `50` prices are excluded from the sum as they have the wrong currency) and is showing that price on all rows (including those with $ currency).